# Where is the setup customization menu in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create a netsuite suitelet and I have the code and I uploaded it to the file cabinet via the netsuite eclipse plugin.

I'm following the directions and I get to Chapter 7 Step 4, create a script record.

It says to go to Setup -> Customization -> Scripts -> New.
But it doesn't give any context, and I have no customization menu option in my setup menu.

Am I missing something? Am I looking in the wrong place? Is there some access control I'm supposed to have on my account that makes these options come into being?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newest version 2014.2 - it should be in:

Customization > Scripting > Scripts

Or you can use the Global search and put: "page: scripts"

Comment: okay, if I go to the global search box and put in page:scripts and it says 
"No Search Results Match Your Criteria." what does that mean? Thanks for all your help everybody, I'm a real newbie.

Comment: Then you don't have access to it. Contact your administrator and ask for permission for that page.

Answer (score 2):

That is the old link.  There should now be a 'Customizations' at the menu bar.

Comment: I don't have Customzations in my menu bar either. :-(

Comment: @stu which version of NS you are using?

Comment: This is going to sound really dumb, but I don't know and I can't tell. I think I have a pretty low-access account because my dashboard has a widget that says "netsuite account center" and there's an error in it that says "you do not have enough permissions to use this portlet" although I suppose that's an access role thing. There's no help->about type option that tells me what version I'm using.

Comment: I think you have to be logged in with the Administrator account in order to see the Customization menu item.